# I dont know how to make dropdown in java

Tags: java, swing

(using netbeans and java)

```
I have the following
1 text field named input 1 (named x5)
1 text field named input 2 (named plus10)
1 text field named input 3 (named plus5perc)

1 answer field (an uneditable text field)

1 button
```

When a number is placed into either input a calculation is done when the calculate button is pressed e.g. if i put in 2 in input 1 and click the button = input1 * 5 and the answer is displayed in the answer field
when 2 is put into input 2 = (input 2 + 10) * 5
when 2 is put into input 3 = input 3 + 5%

instead of having 3 input fields i would like 1 drop down list and one input

so you choose from the drop down which you want and only have 1 input field.

i don't know how to do dropdowns etc and any help would be appreciated

---

### edit

anyone know how to on load hide the 3 inputs and then show the relivant input once it is selected from the combo box?

Comment: Exact dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2065506/combobox-help-needed probably classmate/homework.

Comment: well this one was made before it and no its not homework.

Background:
the application is a calculator for a taxi company. (see my other posts)
---
edit
---
that other one is a guy i work with who has misinterpreted my email. ignore the other one, please use this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave this a try (hope that's what you want).

With all that links and tutorials already provided, you should have been able to do that (IMO).

That's what it looks like:

[Screenshot http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9557/socombobox.png](http://img97.imageshack.us/img97/9557/socombobox.png)

It does **not** do proper exception handling, does **not** round the results and is **not** really object oriented (just uses hardcoded indexes, be careful when changing).

---

Add the components (called `txtInput`, `cmbChoose`, `btnDo` and `txtResult` in my case.

Edit the `model` property of your `JComboBox`, using `Combo Box Model Editor` and set it to

```
x5
plus10
plus5perc
```

This will generate the following source:

```
cmbChoose.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(
    new String[] { "x5", "plus10", "plus5perc" }));
```

Put the following into your `JButton`s `ActionPerformed` method.

```
try {
    float input = Float.valueOf(txtInput.getText());
    float output = 0;

    switch (cmbChoose.getSelectedIndex()) {
        case 0:
            output = input * 5; break;
        case 1:
            output = input + 10; break;
        case 2:
            output = input * 1.05f;
    }

    txtResult.setText(String.valueOf(output));
} catch (Exception e) {
    txtResult.setText("[Error]");
}
```

Comment: thanks.

i've changed your code slightly.

instead of float i'm using a double and i've implemented a decimal format to round the numbers.

and i've changed the exception to show a jOtionPane

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

The drop down is called combo box in most UIs. The Java swing object is JComboBox

Here's the doc:
http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html

And a tutorial:
http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html

Comment: thanks.
i've tried googling and looked at that and couldn't understand it

Comment: Ok. Well the tutorial is about as clear as it gets. The basic idea with combo boxes is that you populate them with a data object (a list at its simplest), register a change listener to the combo box. The change listener is where all the "intelligence" goes. Whatever the user selected is passed to the event handler, you check that (with if-elseif or a switch) and do something in your application. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about the confusion.

please ignore the other post.

---

### answer from user: italy

two approaches:

(1) Use setVisible - When you create the fields invoke setVisible(false) on each. When a selection is made in the combo box invoke setVisible(true) on the relevant input field and setVisible(false) on the others.

(2) Use one input field - when a selection is made on the combo-box change its name

Comment: how do you set a field to setVisible false?

what event would it be?